# Can't send file to my phone with fastboot through ADB

Tags: android, adb, cyanogenmod, lg

I'm stuck in recovery mode cause I forgot to flash GAPPS on my LG G2 (D802) when I update from CM12 to CM12.1 ROM. My phone is now bootlooping.

As I can't use any external storage I'm trying to send GAPPS package to my phone with fastboot from my windows 7 PC.
But when I do `adb devices` I see my phone as *unauthorized* and I can't push files to it.

I have CWM 6.0.5.0 with PhilZ Touch 6.48.4 and touch GUI revision 1.30 and my ADB version is 1.0.32.

So, I wanted to know how to enable ADB on my device **from the recovery mode** or how to grant access to my device from the computer ?  Or simply if there was another way to achieve this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem in a other way with `adb sideload`.

To install flashable zip on your phone in recovery mode with CWM and ADB, follow these steps from the root of the main menu :

```
1 - Choose install zip  
2 - Install zip from sideload  
3 - Plug the phone to the computer  
4 - Type `adb devices` in the windows command shell from the fastboot directory  
5 - Phone should now be listed as "sideload"  
6 - In the Windows command shell type `adb sideload <filename>`  
7 - Wait while the file is send to your phone  
8 - Once the transfer is complete the file is flashed automatically  
9 - Once the flash is successful unplug your phone and restart it in normal mode  
10 - You can **wipe cache and dalvik cache** to avoid errors
```

My phone is now able to run properly.

P.S: I don't get why this question get down votes at it was clear and concise + the answer was not that hard finally.